# Storing, using custom logic in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing an app where I will give a set of tests/checks to the user through an UI such as:

```
LayerCount
ActiveLayerType
EffectCount
ActiveEffectType
CurrentTool
HasSelection
HasAlpha
etc
```

where the user is able to use them to define a custom logic tree such as:

```
if (LayerCount > 1)
{
    if (ActiveLayerType == LayerType.Blend)
    {
         // #1
    }
    else if (ActiveEffectType == EffectType.GaussianBlur)
    {
         // #2
    }
}
else if (CurrentTool == Tools.QuickSelect)
{
    if (HasSelection)
    {
         // #3
    }
}
```

Basically I am trying to define some sort of value that will return the `Current Level` in his custom logic in some way (let's say `1, 2, 3`, and so on). Because I need to have the actions of the user interpreted differently based on the `Current Level` in his logic.

You could basically say that I am trying to hash a set of values based on the `Current Level`. But the problem is, I don't know how to get the current level to store it as a hash key. If I did, I could write something like:

```
var currentActionSet = ActionSetTable [GetCurrentLevel()]
```

and I would get a set of actions the user can perform based on the current level.

Although it would be more desirable to have these levels have fixed values instead of values starting from 1 to n, based on how they are ordered. So `(ActiveEffectType == EffectType.GaussianBlur)`'s branch would always return a fixed value no matter where it's in the logic tree.

So to sum up, the problems are:

1. How to define a current level value, preferrably fixed?
2. If using this current level value as key is the best approach, or if there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: you could build expression tree based on your logic

Comment: Thanks, do you have any links for this? Also does it solve the problem of accessing the current level? Sorry never built expression trees.

Comment: @Joan: Just a suggestion concerning terminology (but of course you can call it whatever you like): When you mention the word _"level"_ in the same phrase as _"logic tree"_, people might understand this to mean _"depth"_. (In your example, all your "levels" #1, #2, #3 have a depth of 2, since they're all nested inside 2 `if` blocks.) Something like _"decision"_ or _"outcome"_ might be less confusing.

Comment: Thanks stakx, I wasn't sure what that would be called, that's why I used level. Should I change it everywhere in the question?

Comment: @Joan: Your question as it is phrased now can be understood fairly well, so there's no immediate need to change everything. I'd say, call these "levels" whatever you feel suits you (and your users) best. Simply be aware that anyone with some background in computer science (esp. data structures) might at first misunderstand your usage of "level".

Comment: Thanks stakx, I wish I could make the question smaller but this is as little as I could reduce it to. I have some ideas for the solution but just want to see other people's opinions, as this might make things easier, more elegant, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use bitflags and OR them together to make your hashcode?

`int hash = ActiveLayerType | ActiveEffectType | CurrentTool`

Then at some later point you can AND a perticular flag out again:

`if( hash & LayerType.Blend  == LayerType.Blend ) { ... } //will be true if the LayerType.Blend has previously been OR:ed into the hash variable`

You can OR together enums of diffrent types too if you cast them to ints first, make sure that the enum bit values doesnt clash though.

This approach may or may not be practical for you application, but its something to consider :) more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx